# Can Safari on an iPad be controlled with gestures?

Tags: ipad, ios, safari, multi-touch

On the Desktop version of Safari, you can navigate back and forward with a swipe gesture on the trackpad. Setting up other gestures (close tab, new tab, next/previous tab) is trivial with an app like [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/).

I find myself trying to use these gestures, especially the swipes for back and forward, on my iPad (third generation).
**Is there any way to enable gestures for Safari on the iPad?**

I realize that the answer is probably no; Apple isn't much for hidden features/preferences in iOS and there are no BTT equivalents. So, I'm willing to explore alternatives. **Are there any other web browsers for iPad, preferably as similar to Safari as possible, that support gestures?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - [Dolphin Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dolphin-browser/id452204407?mt=8) supports gestures. So do [Atomic Web Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-web-browser-full-screen/id347929410?mt=8) and [Perfect Web Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/perfect-web-browser-extraordinary/id373916467?mt=8).

As you correctly realised the answer is no for Safari, unless you count the four-finger swipe up to get to the current app list, and other system gestures.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few Cydia packages which modify Safari to enable gestures and fullscreen mode. I have used "Fullscreen for Safari" which kind of works but is buggy with the debug console enabled (and the swipes are also buggy) on my iPad3.

I have also tried "Swipe Safari" now and it is far superior to the other one, though I think it costs more. It gives you a lot of options in terms of gestures (one, two, three finger swipes, pulling, multi taps, tap and hold)

Answer (score 1):

Safari for iPad does not support multi-touch gestures beyond those you mention, and there is no additional way to configure it to do so.

It looks like the following browsers offer muti-touch gestures, and might fit your needs:

- [Perfect Web Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/perfect-web-browser-extraordinary/id373916467?mt=8)
- [Atomic Web Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-web-browser/id347929410?mt=8)
- [Dolphin Web Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dolphin-browser/id452204407?mt=8)

Answer (score 1):

only way to get gestures, download manager and other cool thinks on you iOS safari is by jailbreaking.

these are the tweaks which will do a magic for you
-sleipinzer for safari
-swipesafari
-fullscreen safari
-safari download manager